# After deploy on the meteor server app is not showing the web page?

Tags: meteor

I need help for i am develop the meteor Js app, it is working on local meteor but after deploy the app it is not showing the web page ,it shows empty page .I had checking load the entire code but not showing  the page.Please how to solve this problem.

My app url is: hcaresample.meteor.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser console shows this error:

> Uncaught Error: There are multiple templates named 'clientRow'. Each template needs a unique name.

Apparently you have defined this template in two places.

Comment: No i am not using i had checking "ClientRow" is using in one template name and another one is "tr" tag class name it is also modify to "clientrow" but it is not working still same.@Cuberto

Comment: Ok thankq i am checking entire code duplicate template name there in my code it is modify now it is working once again thanq.@Cuberto

Comment: In my case, deeply nested in a package was another package with the same template name. To find, I searched the `.meteor/local` folder and found the offending file.